# How to make EditText read and copy only but not editable

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make my edit box read only but not editable.

User should able to copy from my Edit box but it should not be editable ny user.

please let me know how to do this.

Comment: you can use android:enabled="false" but it can't be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the key listener, so you can do anything except editing

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

The command `text.setTextIsSelectable(true)` requires API 11. For those using lower API's use the following XML:

```
android:inputType="none"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

This will make your `editText` selectable but not editable.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do this is to add this code:

```
textInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
textInput.setTextIsSelectable(true);
textInput.setKeyListener(null);
```

Comment: Simple and works. I set the `InputType` and `TextIsSelectable` attributes in the XML, then `null` the listener in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `TextView` as has been indicated by the other answer, instead of an `EditText`. Then override the Activity's context menu in your `Activity` class as below:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Copy");

    //cast the received View to TextView so that you can get its text
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) v;

     //place your TextView's text in the clipboard
     ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
     clipboard.setText(yourTextView.getText());
}
```

Then simply call `registerForContextMenu(yourTextView);` in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:editable="false" property for the EditText in your layout view file.

Comment: This option will disable the copy ability also

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

/*
 * 
 * To make EditText read and copy only but not editable
 * using
 *   sendReadOnlyCallback(callback);
 * 
 */
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    private InputFilter[] originalFilters = null;
    private boolean internalChange = false;
    private InputFilter[] myInputFilters = null;
    private static ReadonlyCallback sDummyCallback = new ReadonlyCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean isReadOnly() {
            return false;
        }
    };
    private ReadonlyCallback callback = sDummyCallback;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public interface ReadonlyCallback {
        public boolean isReadOnly();
    }

    public void setReadonlyCallback(ReadonlyCallback cb) {
        if (cb == null)
            callback = sDummyCallback;
        else
            callback = cb;
    }

    public void setFilters(InputFilter[] filters) {

        // duplicated from TexView
        originalFilters = new InputFilter[filters.length];
        System.arraycopy(filters, 0, originalFilters, 0, filters.length);

        // funny No. 1 : have to re instantiate `callback`
        // otherwise got `NullPointerExcection` when called from `filter`
        callback = sDummyCallback;

        myInputFilters = new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter() {

            // funny No. 2:
            // have to make refs to `originalfilters`
            // otherwise got `NullPointerExcection` when called from `filter`
            InputFilter[] flts = originalFilters;

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                if (!internalChange && callback.isReadOnly())
                    return dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);
                int filtercount = flts.length;
                if (filtercount == 0)
                    return null;

                // duplicated from InputFilter.AllCaps
                for (int i = 0; i < filtercount; i++) {
                    CharSequence repl = flts[i].filter(source, start, end, dest, start, end);
                    if (repl != null) {
                        source = repl;
                        start = 0;
                        end = repl.length();
                    }
                    if (i == filtercount)
                        return repl;
                }
                return null;
            }
        } };
        super.setFilters(myInputFilters);
    }

    @Override
    public InputFilter[] getFilters() {
        if (myInputFilters == null)
            return super.getFilters();
        return originalFilters;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        internalChange = true;
        super.setText(text, type);
        internalChange = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not this?

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not android developer (Xamarin developer).  I think this will prevent selecting and copying text.